# Applied modifiers are not visible

Tags: modifiers, interface

I have an object with two solidify modifiers added, but the modifiers are not visible in the view pane. How can I see the applied modifiers. This is in Blender 2.91

[image]

Comment: If they are applied you won't see them anymore. Don't apply if you want to keep them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Modifiers are automatic operations that affect an object’s geometry in a **non-destructive way**. With modifiers, you can perform many effects automatically that would otherwise be too tedious to do manually (such as subdivision surfaces) and without affecting the base geometry of your object.

> They work by changing how an object is displayed and rendered, but not the geometry which you can edit directly. You can add several modifiers to a single object to form The Modifier Stack and **Apply a modifier if you wish to make its changes permanent**.

---

> **Apply** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)

> **Makes the modifier “real”**: converts the object’s geometry to match the applied modifier’s results, **and deletes the modifier**.

> **Warning**

> Applying a modifier that is not first in the stack will ignore the stack order (it will be applied as if it was the first one), and may produce undesired results.

(From the [Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/introduction.html?highlight=modifiers))

Comment: Thank you! This clears things up significantly.