# How to remove the box and work with the vertices?

Tags: modifiers

Hi I am new to Blender (and 3d design), I have seen that some people can do this.[image]

I mean that they can create a cube, apply the "Subdivision Surface" modifier to it and be able to modify the object using the vertices that are formed when applying the modifier.

On the other hand, if I create a cube, and apply the modifier "Subdivision Surface", it looks like this
[image]

The object still has the shape of the cube and I can only modify it by modifying the surrounding cube. I would need to know how to remove the cube and be able to modify it using the shape of the object.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apply the modifier - click the little down arrow above the word "Simple", and select "apply"

Comment: See: [how to apply a modifier](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193185/how-to-apply-a-modifier-in-v2-9/193188?)

Comment: Note that there is a big difference between adding a modifier to the object and "applying" the modifier. Using modifiers is a non-destructive operation. Once you "apply" the modifier, the transformation is permanent. Read: [applied modifiers are not visible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/205069/applied-modifiers-are-not-visible/205166?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't edit the modified mesh until you **apply** the modifier, unfortunately.

Modifiers create virtual vertices/edges/faces, but they are not editable, transformations are based on the original mesh. The transformations can become permanent by applying the modifier.

So either apply the subsdivision surface modifier and work from there on, or work with the cube in edit mode.