# How to add more vertices on my object

Tags: objects, edit-mode

The video I'm following has more of those vertices (black dots), on their object and mine doesn't - it is required as I'm about
rip open the object ,and since I don't have more, its impossible to rip where the video is asking.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Apply** the subdivision surface modifier. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> (or use the arrow on the top right) to make the modifier permanent.

[image]

Read:

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/205166/92768

and

[How to apply a modifier in V2.9+](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193185/how-to-apply-a-modifier-in-v2-9/193188#193188)

But if your "tutorial" doesn't explain those concepts, consider looking at one that explains better. Not all videos are "tutorials". Some are just not worth your time.